# Is it possible to convert input data from etherscan to abi?

Tags: etherscan, abi

the contract isnt verified but etherscan knows whats being called. how can we write what we got from the input data back into abi form

Comment: There is 4byte.directory an online databases signatures. Etherescan might have its own database from registered contracts.

Answer (score 0):

The transaction calls the DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE() function without passing any additional parameters, that's all.

Comment: yes but like if i wanted to call that too without how could i write the abi for that? (the contract is unverified) soz for being a noob ><

Comment: abi.encodeWithSignature("DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE()")